# How to add user authentication with ReactJS Components

Tags: reactjs, authentication, components, render

I want to implement a user authentication based on ReactJS component. I'm new to ReactJS and it's a group software project, so we don't use webhooks but components. The Authentication itself is working but not the rendering afterwards of the content.

In the app.js file I used conditional rendering, to either show the content or the login page:

if (this.getToken('token') === null || this.getToken('token') === undefined) {

```
  shownComponent = <LoginComponent token={this.state.token} setToken={this.setToken} />;
} else {
  shownComponent = <MainComponent />;
}
```

In the LoginComponent I implemented the following logic:

```
registerUser = () => {
    const data = {
        userName: this.state.userName,
        userPassword: this.state.userPassword
    }
    return fetch('/users/createUser', {
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
        .then((data) => {
            if(data.status === 200){
                console.log('User has been stored to database');
                return true
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log( error.response.request) );
}

loginUser = () => {
    return fetch('/login',{ headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        } })
        .then((response) =>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) =>{
            return data;
        });

}

login = async () => {

    this.setState({loggedin: true})
    const registered = await this.registerUser()
    const userToken = await this.loginUser();
    this.props.setToken(userToken)

}
```

after calling the login function from the login form (not copy pasted in here) it would only re-render the login page but not redirect back to the app.js and render now the main content.